# Autosuggest API returns deleted results

Tags: here-api

I am trying you use youre [`autosuggest API`](https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest)
but there is a problem, that you are returning places even though they have already been deleted.

For instance there is a place that is deleted in your map called **Jeder Ist Tanzbar** in Germany, that when [calling the API](https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?q=Jeder%20Ist%20Tanzbar&app_id=qnJlIRln6r1tDdOnG5vU&app_code=D28pQMtPZbJUiR42s7mtvg&pretty&X-Map-Viewport=11.24931,51.3512,14.78073,53.55438&Accept-Language=en&at=52.5063,13.44518;cgen=gps) is returned, but if you look at the map, you can see it's already deleted as you can see in the gray box in the right.

IMHO it's a bug, could you address this please?

Example photo of the map 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you encounter such more errors.
Please use

1. Map creator (locate the poi and make the change, Here team will review and approve it)
2. Use Map Feedback API :

> developer.here.com/documentation/map-feedback/dev_guide/topics/resource-type-response-feedback.html